# gls file does not update due to order of \bibliography and \appendix

Tags: texstudio, glossaries

I am using the following code to create a list of symbols and abbreviations for my project:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[automake, acronyms, symbols, toc, nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{AR}{name={AR},description={Auto regression model}}
\newglossaryentry{symb:I}{name={$I$},description={number of agents}, type=symbols}

\begin{document}
This is a test \gls{AR}. 

\printglossary[title={Abbreviations}]
\printglossary[type=symbols, style=super, title=Symbols]

\appendix
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{library}

\end{document}
```

Which is working perfectly fine. However, I want to move my References **before** the Appendix: (the exact same code but different order of appendix and bibliography):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[automake, acronyms, symbols, toc, nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{AR}{name={AR},description={Auto regression model}}
\newglossaryentry{symb:I}{name={$I$},description={number of agents}, type=symbols}

\begin{document}
This is a test \gls{AR}. 

\printglossary[title={Abbreviations}]
\printglossary[type=symbols, style=super, title=Symbols]

% here I changed the order!
\appendix
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{library}

\end{document}
```

When I do that, I get the following error:

[image]

Because Latex does not update my .gls file anymore. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Your last MWE is incomplete (there is no `\end{document}`. Additionally we do not have the `library.bib` file, so we cannot check your example. Please make your your examples are self contained such that others can test them.